# Route subnet through a VPN gateway with OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn

A small company I work at is getting rid of an office soon and it has fallen onto me to migrate the currently
on-prem-hosted VPN (just a Zyxel Zywall 110 device) into a cloud-based VM. I am not that experienced in networking (backend-dev-turned-ops)
so I would like to validate if the following approach will work.

---

I have a dedicated VM where I've set up OpenVPN Access Server and the basics are working well, people can connect,
all good.

There is one catch though, the current VPN forwards a certain IP range through a "tunnel" into a partner company's internal network.
It looks like this:

```
if dest_addr in '172.30.239.0/25':
    route through gw 194.xxx.xxx.xxx
else:
    route through gw 0.0.0.0
```

As an example, when connected to the VPN, my traffic would be routed as such:

```
dest 1.2.3.4       => me -> VPN server -> its internet gateway -*-> 1.2.3.4
dest 172.30.239.10 => me -> VPN server -> partner network gateway (194.xxx.xxx.xxx) -(internal network routing)-> 172.30.239.10
```

Where the connection from our router to the partner company's VPN GW is done via IKEv1 with pre-shared key (judging from the router's web UI, as that's all the "documentation" I have).

Some ascii art depicting the setup below. I am replacing `Router` with a VM.

```
            +-----------------+           [     Partner infra, this has to stay the same     ]
            | Router          |           194.xxx.xxx.xxx            e.g. 172.30.239.75
            | --------------- |   IKEv1   +-------------+       +-------------------------+
User -----> | 172.30.239.0/25-| --------> | VPN gateway |-----> | Internal network server |
            |     default     |           +-------------+       +-------------------------+
            |        |        |
            +--------+--------+
                     |
                     |
                 internet
```

The OpenVPN Access Server does not support anything like this by itself (or I haven't been able to find that config), so I thought I could do it on the VM level.
If I connect the OS to the VPN gateway with something like Strongswan and configure appropriate routing in `iptables`, could
this work? Would the traffic of users connected to the OpenVPN server going to the `172.30.239.0/25` range get routed
through to the Strongswan's connection, or is this approach fundamentally wrong? What are my options?

Thanks!

Comment: For me, some things are still unclear. The condition above: 'if the clients vpn-ip address is inside this range, let the default route be ...' So there is a second IP range the VPN clients can get? this is mentioned nowhere - otherwise you would not need this condition... Can you clarify ?

Comment: I see I probably used bad naming here. When I said "client" I meant "client of our company" (and their internal network), not the "VPN client computer".  I will edit the question and fix this. But to answer your question, no, the VPN users (employees of our company) all get addresses from a single IP range. What the condition applies to is the _destination_ address of outbound traffic.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are a little bit clearer now. Of course OpenVPN has an option for your problem: If you want that the VPN client routes traffic for the network 1.2.3.0/25 through your VPN tunnel, use the option `push` ([source](https://linux.die.net/man/8/openvpn)) :

```
--push option
    Push a config file option back to the client for remote execution. Note that
 option must be enclosed in double quotes (""). The client must specify --pull in
 its config file. The set of options which can be pushed is limited by both
 feasibility and security. Some options such as those which would execute scripts
 are banned, since they would effectively allow a compromised server to execute
 arbitrary code on the client. Other options such as TLS or MTU parameters cannot
 be pushed because the client needs to know them before the connection to the
 server can be initiated.
```

So, you have to add in your openvpn server configuration

```
push "route 1.2.3.0 255.255.255.128"
```

This tells the openvpn client, that it should route all traffic going to that subnet through the vpn tunnel. And, of course, on the server itself, the correct route must be in place, too - But I guess this route is probably already in place.

**[UPDATE]**
My answer is missing some basic information about routing. Any network device can act as a gateway - this is what home routers do. Routing is not done with `iptables` - that is a tool to modify the linux built-in kernel firewall. A routing decision is done with the help of the [routing table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table) (I will talk only about IPv4 here for briefity). For every IP packet which is being sent, the routing table is taken into account, starting with host-only routes ( /32 subnet), taking the most "precise" route it can find. So, the default route ( /0 subnet ) is taken only, if no matching route with a more "precise" subnet is being found.

Routing all traffic through the VPN tunnel is easy. OpenVPN uses the `redirect-gateway` directive for that. So either, you put that directive into all client configurations, or you put a

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

into your server config. With the option def1, two routes with 128.0.0.0 subnets is being used instead of one 0.0.0.0 subnet route - which is being done to avoid that the new default route is being overwritten by the DHCP client.

Coming to the routes on your server. As the server is the endpoint of an IPSec tunnel (going to your partner), the software (strongswan?) already installed the necessary routes on that server, such that the traffic for the remote networks is being routed through the IPSec tunnel.

Let me draw a picture with example networks and routes for a better understanding.
Think of the following network:

```
A ---------- B -------- C --------- D
```

- A is a OpenVPN client with ip 10.8.0.2
- B is the OpenVPN server with IP 10.8.0.1 and 172.16.0.1
- C is the remote IPSec endpoint inside your partner's network with the IP 172.16.0.2 and 192.168.0.1
- D is a network device inside the partner's network with the IP 192.168.0.10

in this example setup, you have three networks:

- the OpenVPN network
- the IPSec network
- the partner network

Device A has the route: `0.0.0.0/0 gw 10.8.0.1`
Server B has two routes: one default gateway going to the ISP, and: `192.168.0.0/24 gw 172.16.0.2`
Server C has two routes: one default gateway going to the partner's ISP, and: `10.8.0.0/24 gw 172.16.0.1`
For Device D, only the default route `0.0.0.0/0 gw 192.168.0.1` is required.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but won't this setup make the client traffic go through the VPN server _only_ for a specific destination subnet? The intention is that from the client side, _all traffic_ should be routed through the VPN tunnel. Only at the VPN server side should it be decided where to further send the incoming packets. | About the `correct route must be in place` - are you talking about an `iptables` route here?

Comment: yes, you are correct - this setup will route only specific traffic through the vpn tunnel. I might have missed the requirement, that all traffic should go through the tunnel. And no, I am talking about routes - iptables is mainly a firewall. I will edit my answer according to your needs... Usually, routing all traffic through VPN is an unwanted behaviour, since it is unnecessary traffic in most cases - that is why I assumed that you do not want / need this.

Comment: I understand, thanks. Only routing particular subnets would be an improvement but one that can be done later. Right now I want to get a 1:1 working setup which we have now, which has all the traffic going through the VPN tunnel (which I expect should be easier to do?). The only missing piece is this server-side traffic routing

Comment: I enhanced my answer - with an example how the routing could work. Note that every subnet which is supposed to be routed through an ipsec tunnel needs to be anounced on both ends of the tunnel - this setup can get quite ugly...

Comment: don't know if this helps you, I set on the OpenVPN server the default Gateway to reach everything onsite and using nat to communicate with the rest so in fact, if I understand you correctly you want to reach any resources which belong to your VM? this is indeed possible

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for us to only route the OpenVPN subnet through the OpenVPN tunnel:

```
pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway
route-nopull
route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```